# Can I add another filter option to element index views?

Tags: plugin-development, control-panel

What I am trying to do is adjust the entry index page to be more specific for our use case, I have already sorted out extra columns but I want to sort or filter by entry type. Of course I can already sort by `typeId` using `modifyEntrySortableAttributes` but this is not ideal.

I either want to be able to sort by an entry type's name using `modifyEntrySortableAttributes` or better still insert another filter button of all the types in-between the status filter and the search bar, see mock-up below.

[image]

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made a small plugin that nests Entry Types under their section in the sources list that might be good enough for what you're after:

https://gist.github.com/mdcpepper/548fd04939e040507960

Comment: Excellent thanks Mike - I'll take a look and get back to you!

Comment: Great - this is doing enough for what I need, not quite the UI I was after but it does the job - thanks Mike :)

Answer (score 1):

The "All types" filter button would be sweet, but as far as I know, there's no way to implement that without hacking the CP w/ JS, as Craft doesn't expose any relevant hooks. I'd be a bit cautious with stuff like that, especially now with 3.0 on the horizon.

Shameless plug:
The [DashCols](https://github.com/mmikkel/DashCols-Craft) plugin (which I wrote) will let you display and sort on entry type. Alas – DashCols uses `typeId` for sorting, not the *name* like you want. Having the option to sort on the types' ID *or* name would be a cool feature, though – I'll try to get that in there some day and will update this answer if/when I do.

Comment: Yeah - I had the same issue with `typeId`, couldn't for the life of me work out how to sort by `name`. In the end I went with `typeId` but just made sure the order of the Entry Types was alphabetical...